# JS Error in IE 8... "Object Required"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am implementing pagination on a project currently in progress but I am getting an error with this piece of code in IE8:

```
var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
```

Here is the error:

```
Message: Object required
```

I am using this open source code for the pagination:

http://en.newinstance.it/2006/09/27/client-side-html-table-pagination-with-javascript/

Now my question would be, is this a valid piece of code for ie 8? if not what could I substitute to obtain the same results of the given piece of code? (or how can i fix this error :P)

If more information is needed, I'll try my best to provide.

Comment: Is your data coming from the database is in a small nos only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `document.getElementById(tableName)` is not finding the table which you're expecting, and so it returns `null`. `null.rows` is not valid, and so there's an error there.

I'd recommend splitting that line into two and checking that the element is found before continuing:

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableName),
    rows;
if (table) {
    rows = table.rows;
} else {
    alert("Couldn't find table with id: " + tableName);
}
```

Comment: Ah that is exactly what is going on, the table is being created dynamically using jquery, and then the container was sliding down with results on the table, I am calling the pagination code in the slidedown, figuring it would find the table, but I'll have to over look my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better to use jquery for this.
IF you use a jquery "if object is not found - no error will be returned"

Use it like this:

```
var table =  $('#tableName');
```